# How to get List from Page in Spring Data REST

Tags: java, spring, pagination, spring-data, spring-restcontroller

I am using `JPARespository` for all my CRUD operation.
Recently I wanted to implement sorting, so I went ahead with `Pagable`.

The problem is, I want the repository methods to return `List` objects, I use them in my service layer.

How can I achieve this, is there a way to convert these `Page` objects to `List`?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you use pageable in a jpa repository method, spring will always return a Page not a List. I suggest you have a service method that calls the repository method and extracts the contents of the Page result into a list.

So if your repository method is thus:

```
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface RecordRepository extends JpaRepository<Record, Integer>{                      
     Page<Record> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

then you can have a service class which has a method that calls the repository method

```
@Service
public class RecordService{

   @Autowired
   RecordRepository recordRepository;

  public List<Record> findAll(PageRequest pageRequest){
    Page<Record> recordsPage = recordRepository.findAll(pageRequest);
    return recordsPage.getContent();
  }
}
```

so in your calling class instead of calling the repository directly you can just use the service. thus:

```
public class MyRecordImpl{
   @Autowired
  RecordService recordService;

  public void doSomething(){
      int page = 0; int pageSize = 5;
      List<Record> recordList = recordService.findAll(new PageRequest(page, pageSize, new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "recordId")));
     //do other implementations here
   }
}
```

Comment: but does the `.getContent()` return everything from all the pages, or just that single page's data?

Comment: @mmcrae the .getContent() returns just that single page's data

Comment: How to get everything from all the pages and convert them to list?

Comment: @gavinSong iterate through each page and add the content to a single combined List

Answer (score 14):

The simplest way to fetch all your results at once is to use [Pageable.unpaged()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable.html#unpaged--), like below:

```
Page<Employee> allEmployees = employeeRepository.findAll(Pageable.unpaged());
allEmployees.getContent();
```

But if you are concerned about retrieving too much data at once and instead prefer to do the retrieval in small chunks, you can use a service or repository method similar to below:

```
private List<Employee> findAll() {
    List<Employee> allEmployees = new ArrayList<>();

    // First page of employees -- 5000 results per page
    PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(0, 5000);
    Page<Employee> employeePage = employeeRepository.findAll(pageRequest);
    allEmployees.addAll(employeePage.getContent());

    // All the remaining employees
    while (employeePage.hasNext()) {
        Page<Employee> nextPageOfEmployees = employeeRepository.findAll(employeePage.nextPageable());
        allEmployees.addAll(nextPageOfEmployees.getContent());

        // update the page reference to the current page
        employeePage = nextPageOfEmployees;
    }

    return allEmployees;
}
```

Check this [page](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-data-part-5-paging-and-sorting) for advantages and disadvantages on fetching the data in chunks.

Comment: Good, Thanks!. I found out more `Sort.unsorted()`. Good day!

Answer (score 2):

I know I am late, but, this is the first option it pops in google and people may need more answers when all the information of all pages needs to be converted into a list...

One aproximation can be:

```
xRepository.findAll(new PageRequest(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE)).getContent();
```

The problem here is that spring sets the maximum size to 1000 so you are going to get a list of maximum 1000 elements.

An other way of doing it can be multiple find with diferent page indexes and then adding  the results into a list with getContent():

```
Page<T> pageData = xRepository.findAll(new PageRequest(0, 20));
List<T> finalList = pageData.getContent();
while(!pageData.isLast()){
    pageData = xRepository.findAll(pageData.nextPageable());
    List<T> listData = pageData.getContent();
    //append listData into finalList
}
```

Comment: Hello, you should always specify the index `PageRequest.of(0, 20, Sort.Direction.ASC, "id")`